# In Final Cut Pro 7, is there a way to playback a Ganged Browser clip in real time with the Canvas/Timeline?

Tags: final-cut-pro

Opening a clip from the browser and ganging it with the Timeline, then playing the timeline, only results in the Viewer being updated when playback stops. The only real-time ganging you get is when you are scrubbing clips.

Is there any way around this, or is it just not possible and/or only possible with multicam clips?